# Add incrementing ID to obj in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, foreach

Trying to add an ID to each object in an array. And if the id already exists the id will increment by 1, trying to get an auto increment function going. The problem is that with this function every object either gets the same ID when running the for loop inside the for each statement or I get cannot read `obj.id of undefined` if the loop runs outside.

```
function addId(arr, obj) {
  obj.id;
  arr.forEach(function(obj) {
    obj.id = 0;
    return obj.id;
  });
  for(var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    if(obj.id == obj.id) obj.id++;
  }
};
```

Comment: `forEach` will have current element as an argument in the callback.

Comment: Can you add what `arr` looks like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code. First of all `obj.id;` doesn't do anything. So you should get rid of it. Also inside you `forEach` you're assigning the value `0` as an id to each object, but in you second loop you're checking if the id of the `obj` which is passed in as an argument is the same as itself, therefore the check will always yield `true` and then you're incrementing the id of the passed in `obj`.

So you're never manipulating the objects inside your array after setting their id attribute to `0`.

You could use the index as the value for the id.

Also if needed you could consider to use something like `Object.assign` to prevent altering the original objects inside your array.

```js
function addId(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(obj, index) {
    return Object.assign({}, obj, { id: index });
  });
};

// test
const input = [ { a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }, { a: 4 }];
const output = addId(input);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated version with arrow functions and spread

```js
const addId=(arr)=> {
  return arr.map((obj, index)=>  {
    return ({...obj,id: index })
  });
};

// test
const input = [ { a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }, { a: 4 }];
addId(input)
console.log(addId(input))
```

Or Even cleaner

```js
const addId=(arr)=> arr.map((obj, index)=>({...obj,id: index }));

// test
const input = [ { a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }, { a: 4 }];
addId(input)
console.log(addId(input))
```